# How to bind TableRow in asp.net table control using loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, controls, tablerow

```
Table _Table = (Table)Session["Sample"];
for(int counter = 0; counter < _Table.Rows.Count; counter++)
{
   myTable.Rows.Add(_Table.Rows[counter]);
}
```

- Here myTable is webserver control. _Table is dynamic webserver control.

Problem:

While i am adding to myTable, Particular tablerow removed from _Table.Rows collection. So, I loss my data from session. Is there any possibilities to bind row without lossing the session items. Please guide me.

Thanks Advance.

Comment: Can you do `_Table.Rows[counter].Clone()`?

Comment: Is it one particular row gets removed? What's use case here which forces you to store control in session?

Comment: I loaded _Table from the session. Its reference object. So, While items removed from _Table object it automatically removed from session.

Comment: Not one row. based on added items multiple TableRow removed

Comment: @kblok- It don't have an option for clone

Comment: What stops you from using datagrid or gridview for table like display and storing data only in the session. Data can be collection of objects. The best thing would be store only some values in session which can help you to retrieve data from database which you display in the UI.

Comment: I have to bind dynamic controls in table's each cells. Gridview and datagrid or more complex for this. So i am going with Table control :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the best and easiest way to accomplish our expectation.

Instead of storing Table in session. We can store List in session. So, that we can do all  the collection operation.

```
Table _Table = (List<TableRow>)Session["Sample"];
for(int counter = 0; counter < _Table.Rows.Count; counter++)
{
    myTable.Rows.Add(_Table.Rows[counter]);
}
```

So, 
  During dynamic binding it will not remove from collection.